# The relation between the trace of a positive definite matrix and the trace of the inverse of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, positive-definite, matrix-analysis

How to prove this inequality, that:
$$Tr(\mathbf{X})\geq \frac{N^2}{Tr(\mathbf{X}^{-1})}$$
where $\mathbf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ is an arbitrary positive definite matrix.

> Horn R A, Johnson C R. Matrix analysis[M]. Cambridge university press, 2012.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the fact that if $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $X$ then the eigenvalues of $X^{-1}$ are ${1 \over \lambda_k}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_N$ be the eigenvalues of $X$, which are positive real numbers by assumption.  Then the eigenvalues of $X^{-1}$ are $\lambda_i^{-1}$.  Clearing denominators and expressing trace in terms of eigenvalues, The inequality becomes

$$\left(\sum \lambda_i\right)\left(\sum 1/\lambda_i\right)\geq N^2.$$

Define $v$ to be the vector whose $i$th component is $\lambda_i^{1/2}$ and $w$ the vector whose $i$th component is $\lambda_i^{-1/2}$.  The inequality is then Cauchy-Schwarz applied to $v$ and $w$.

Answer (score 1):

As copper.hat suggests in the comments, use the fact that the eigenvalues of $X^{-1}$ are $1/\lambda_k$.

Then 
$$\newcommand\Tr{\operatorname{Tr}}\Tr(X)\Tr(X^{-1}) =
\sum_{i=1}^N\lambda_i \sum_{j=1}^N\lambda_j^{-1}
=\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i} + \sum_{i> j} \left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_j} + \frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_i}\right)$$
Then for any $t>0$, $t+\frac{1}{t} \ge 2$. This yields
$$\Tr(X)\Tr(X^{-1}) \ge N + \sum_{i > j} 2 = N + 2\frac{N(N-1)}{2} = N+N^2-N = N^2,$$
as desired.